# How to Calculate Two Tables Totalsum Value in Angularjs?

Tags: html, css, angularjs, meanjs

I am using MEAN stack in my application with AngularJS as my front-end. How to total sum two values in angularjs , actually we have two tables, first table is filtered with `filter:{raised: 'false'}`  and second table is filtered with `filter:{raised: 'true'}` and we got  the total sum values for both table in `commision` then I'M expecting to calculate `commision` totalsum values like `A + B` as a `45 + 19 answer = 64`...[My Plunker](http://plnkr.co/edit/WwCEspZpzIOKDLXr88hF?p=preview).

- We have two table so I want to calculate first table `commision`  total sum value and second table `commision` totalsum value.
- the both tables are filtered with ng-module value **for example** :- first table is filtered with `filter:{raised: 'false'}`  and second table is filtered with `filter:{raised: 'true'}`
- Expectation exmaple:- fisrt table commision is `45`, and second table commision is `19` , we need to calculate these to value in third table like `A + B` answer should be `64`.
- I have given the plunker as reference [plunker](http://plnkr.co/edit/WwCEspZpzIOKDLXr88hF?p=preview) please any one knows the solution help us.

**My controller:-**
  **Commision totalsum filter:-**

```
    .filter('totalSumCV', function () {
   return function (data, key1, key2) {        
       if (angular.isUndefined(data) && angular.isUndefined(key1)  && angular.isUndefined(key2)) 
           return 0;

       var sum = 0;
       angular.forEach(data,function(v,k){
           sum = sum + (parseFloat(v[key1]) * parseFloat(v[key2])/100);
       });
       return sum.toFixed(2);
   }
})
```

**My Html:-**

```
<tr ng-repeat="mani in resultValue=(sryarndebitnote |  filter:{raised: 'false'} )">

    <td>A = {{resultValue | totalSumCV:'invoice_value_fob':'percentage_commission'}}</td>

</tr>


  <tr ng-repeat="mani in resultValue=(sryarndebitnote |  filter:{raised: 'true'} )">

    <td>B = {{resultValue | totalSumCV:'invoice_value_fob':'percentage_commission'}}</td>

</tr>
```

I have tried to calculate both table commision totalsum value like :-

```
<td >C = {{((resultValue | totalSumCV:'invoice_value_fob':'percentage_commission') * 1) + ((resultValue | totalSumCV:'invoice_value_fob':'percentage_commission')*1)}}</td>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should take **different variables for the result set** to achieve this,

Here is your required answer,

```js
var app = angular.module('plunker', []);


app.filter('sumOfValue', function () {
    return function (data, key) {
        debugger;
        if (angular.isUndefined(data) && angular.isUndefined(key))
            return 0;        
        var sum = 0;
        
        angular.forEach(data,function(v,k){
            sum = sum + parseFloat(v[key]);
        });        
        return sum.toFixed(2);
    }
}).filter('totalSumCV', function () {
   return function (data, key1, key2) {        
       if (angular.isUndefined(data) && angular.isUndefined(key1)  && angular.isUndefined(key2)) 
           return 0;
       
       var sum = 0;
       angular.forEach(data,function(v,k){
           sum = sum + (parseFloat(v[key1]) * parseFloat(v[key2])/100);
       });
       return sum.toFixed(2);
   }
}).controller('MainCtrl', function($scope) {
  $scope.sryarndebitnote = [
{
"_id": "57ecb2861365a8150a34c660",
"user": {
"_id": "57400c32bd07906c1308e2cf",
"displayName": "mani selvam"
},
"__v": 0,
"created": "2016-09-29T06:19:50.046Z",
"shipment_id": "57dc0ad6a752016f1638c6bc",
"raised": false,
"conversion_rate": "62",
"percentage_tds": "10",
"percentage_servicetax": "15",
"percentage_commission": "3",
"invoice_value_fob": "300",
"invoice_value_cif": "50",
"invoice_quantity": "40",
"supplier_name": "asd",
"buyer_name": "Rohit"
},


{
"_id": "57ecb2861365a8150a34c660",
"user": {
"_id": "57400c32bd07906c1308e2cf",
"displayName": "mani selvam"
},
"__v": 0,
"created": "2016-09-29T06:19:50.046Z",
"shipment_id": "57dc0ad6a752016f1638c6bc",
"raised": false,
"conversion_rate": "62",
"percentage_tds": "10",
"percentage_servicetax": "15",
"percentage_commission": "6",
"invoice_value_fob": "600",
"invoice_value_cif": "50",
"invoice_quantity": "40",
"supplier_name": "asd",
"buyer_name": "Rohit"
},

{
"_id": "57ecb2861365a8150a34c660",
"user": {
"_id": "57400c32bd07906c1308e2cf",
"displayName": "mani selvam"
},
"__v": 0,
"created": "2016-09-29T06:19:50.046Z",
"shipment_id": "57dc0ad6a752016f1638c6bc",
"raised": true,
"conversion_rate": "62",
"percentage_tds": "10",
"percentage_servicetax": "15",
"percentage_commission": "4",
"invoice_value_fob": "400",
"invoice_value_cif": "50",
"invoice_quantity": "40",
"supplier_name": "asd",
"buyer_name": "Rohit"
},

{
"_id": "57ecb2861365a8150a34c660",
"user": {
"_id": "57400c32bd07906c1308e2cf",
"displayName": "mani selvam"
},
"__v": 0,
"created": "2016-09-29T06:19:50.046Z",
"shipment_id": "57dc0ad6a752016f1638c6bc",
"raised": true,
"conversion_rate": "62",
"percentage_tds": "10",
"percentage_servicetax": "15",
"percentage_commission": "3",
"invoice_value_fob": "100",
"invoice_value_cif": "50",
"invoice_quantity": "40",
"supplier_name": "asd",
"buyer_name": "Rohit"
},]

});
```

```css
/* Put your css in here */

body {
    font-size: 14px;
}

table
{
    border-collapse:collapse;
}
table, td, th
{
    border:1px solid black;
}
td{
    padding: 2px;
}
.servicetaxinclusivetrue:before{
  color: green!important;
  content: "\f00c";
}
.servicetaxinclusivefalse:before{
  color: red!important;
  content: "\f00d";
}
.servicetaxexclusivetrue:before{
  color: green!important;
  content: "\f00c";
}
.servicetaxexclusivefalse:before{
  color: red!important;
  content: "\f00d";
}
.margin{
      margin-top: 20px;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html ng-app="plunker">

  <head>
    <meta charset="utf-8" />
    <title>AngularJS Plunker</title>
    <script>document.write('<base href="' + document.location + '" />');</script>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="style.css" />
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="http://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/font-awesome/4.6.3/css/font-awesome.min.css">
    <script data-require="angular.js@1.4.x" src="https://code.angularjs.org/1.4.12/angular.js" data-semver="1.4.9"></script>
    <script src="app.js"></script>
  </head>

  <body ng-controller="MainCtrl">
    
    
    <table ng-table="tableParams"  class="table table-bordered ">
      <thead>
         <tr>
           
            <th rowspan="2"> S.No </th>
            <th rowspan="2"> fob </th>
            <th rowspan="2"> Commision </th>
            <th rowspan="2">Quantity</th>
            </tr>
    </thead>
       <tr ng-repeat="mani in resultValue=(sryarndebitnote |  filter:{raised: 'false'} )"> 
          <td >{{$index + 1}}</td>
            <td >{{mani.invoice_value_fob}}</td>
              <td >{{(mani.invoice_value_fob * (mani.percentage_commission / 100)) | number:2}}</td>
                 <td >{{mani.invoice_quantity}}</td>
           </tr>
               <tr>
                 <td>sum</td>
                 <td>{{resultValue | sumOfValue:'invoice_value_fob'}}</td>
                 <td>A = {{resultValue | totalSumCV:'invoice_value_fob':'percentage_commission'}}</td>
                 <td></td>
               </tr>
      </table>
              
    <table ng-table="tableParams"  class="margin table table-bordered ">
      <thead>
        <tr>
            
            <th rowspan="2"> S.No </th>
            <th rowspan="2"> fob </th>
            <th rowspan="2"> Commision </th>
            <th rowspan="2">Quantity</th>
            </tr>
    </thead>
      <tr ng-repeat="mani in resultValue2=(sryarndebitnote | filter:{raised: 'true'})"> 
        <td >{{$index + 1}}</td>
           <td >{{mani.invoice_value_fob}}</td>
             <td >{{(mani.invoice_value_fob * (mani.percentage_commission / 100)) | number:2}}</td>
                <td >{{mani.invoice_quantity}}</td>
              
          </tr>
               <tr>
                 <td>sum</td>
                 <td>{{resultValue2 | sumOfValue:'invoice_value_fob'}}</td>
                 <td>B = {{resultValue2 | totalSumCV:'invoice_value_fob':'percentage_commission'}}</td>
                 <td></td>
               </tr>
      </table>
              
    <table ng-table="tableParams"  class="margin table table-bordered ">
      <thead>
        <tr>
            
          <th rowspan="2"> S.No </th>
            <th rowspan="2"> A + B </th>
          </tr>
    </thead>
             
            <td >{{resultValue2 | totalSumCV:'invoice_value_fob':'percentage_commission'}}</td>
                <td >C = {{((resultValue | totalSumCV:'invoice_value_fob':'percentage_commission') * 1) + ((resultValue2 | totalSumCV:'invoice_value_fob':'percentage_commission')*1)}}</td>
              
          </table>
  </body>

</html>
```

**Pls run the code.**

[Here is the plunker](https://plnkr.co/edit/tZjnDyNH1FCevNS1gUad?p=preview)